# Non-orientable 3-manifolds

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds

I am reading *[Non-orientable 3-manifolds of small complexity](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0166-8641(03)00043-9)* (Topology and its Applications **133** (2003) pp 157-178, arXiv:[math/0211092](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0211092)), by Amendola and Martinelli. In this work $\mathbb P^2$-irreducible complexity-6 manifolds are listed. There are five of them. I wonder about the following non-orientable manifolds.

1. Take $S^2\times I$ and glue its top sphere to its bottom sphere with the antipodal homeomorphism or with a reflection in plane homeomorphism. Let's denote it by $S^2\widetilde\times S^1$.
2. $\mathbb P^2\times S^1$

I assume that those two manifolds are not $\mathbb P^2$-irreducible. I don't know how to embed $\mathbb P^2$ into the first one. The preposition 1.3 on page 5 of the abovementioned work says that a Stiefel-Whitney surface cannot be a sphere. It seems to me that it is sphere for the first manifold.

Both of them have double cover $S^2\times S^1$, and the fundamental groups are $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z + \mathbb Z_2$. What are the fundamental groups of the five manifolds of complexity 6 in the above work?

At the same time I have the following additional questions about non-orientable 3-manifolds.

**A**. In case of surfaces we obtain every non-orientable one, except for the Klein bottle, by the connected sum of an orientable one with $\mathbb RP^2$. Is there an analog in 3-manifolds? I.e. Is every non-orientable closed 3-manifold being connected sum of orientable one and $S^2\widetilde\times S^1$ ? (clarified on **2018-09-03**)

**B**. A non-orientable surface with a removed disk is embeddable in $\mathbb R^3$. Can we embed a non-orientable $M^3$ with removed ball into $\mathbb R^4$ ?

**C**. Is the regular neighborhood of a loop changing orientation in a 3-manifold homeomorphic to a solid Klein bottle ?

**EDIT 2018-07-08** I add following new question.

**D**. Each non-orientable surface is double covered by orientable one. We can ask whether every 3-manifold with infinite fundamental group is double cover of some non-orientable one.

The answer to my question **A** is negative but still it seems that we can somehow convert orientable manifold into non-orientable by attaching handle which change orientation. When Stiefel-Whitney surface is sphere then it is the case.

Comment: (A) No. What you see in dimension 2 is a very special case. (B) No again. There are obstructions to embedding punctured 3-manifolds in $\mathbb R^4$, for example there is one using the torsion linking form.  (C) The boundary of a regular neighbourhood, yes. The neighbourhood itself is the associated disc bundle to the Klein bottle.

Comment: Thank you again. At least we can sort irreducible non-orientable 3-manifolds by genus of Stiefel-Whitney surface.

Comment: The notion of P2-irreducible contains in particular irreducible. So there are no non-trivial spheres.

Comment: by a full Kleinbottle you mean solid Kleinbottle?

Comment: Sorry for my language. I mean $D^1\times D^2$ with top and bottom $D^2$ glued with reflection homeomorphism. I guess this is called "solid Klein bottle".

Comment: @BrunoMartelli Thank you for clarification. In your work there is written that Stiefel Whitney torus is incompressible. Can we think of following procedure producing non-orientable manifold ? Let $\Sigma$ be incompressible torus in oriented closed 3-manifold $M$ such that boundary of $R(\Sigma)$ is two tori. Remove neighborhood $R(\Sigma)$ and glue it back by changing orientation on one end. Resulting manifold is not orientable, because each path intersecting $\Sigma$ change orientation. (I wonder whether we had essential path intersecting $\Sigma$ it in one point in manifold $M$ ?)

Comment: @RyanBudney Why the answer to (A) is no? I think that "if the connected sum is orientable" implies that both pieces are orientable. This is easy to prove by taking the "holonomic" definition of orientability. i.e. taking close paths and checking if a framing changes orientation when you run a full loop.

Comment: @Paul: the boundary of a tubular neighbourhood of a non-orientable loop in a surface is a circle.  In a 3-manifold that boundary is a Klein bottle.   That's ultimately the reason -- there's more diversity among co-dimension one submanifolds in 3-manifolds than in 2-manifolds.

Comment: @RyanBudney I don't understand why your comment invalidates my argument. (A) suggests that by considering any orientable 3-manifold and taking the connected sum with $S^2 \widetilde{\times} S^1$ we get an non-orientable manifold.  See for example the second anwser in this MS question that says that if a connected sum is orientable so are both of its summands https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50002/connected-sums-of-closed-orientable-manifold-is-orientable

Comment: @RyanBudney or if you are not satisfied I can try to elaborate more on the argument I suggested. But Jason DeVito's argument suffices I think.

Comment: @Paul: not every non-orientable 3-manifold has such a summand.  That's the point I was making.

Comment: @RyanBudney ok, but if I understood correctly, as stated, the OP is asking for an analogy “I take connected sums with RP2 to generate non orientable surfaces” but in 3 dimensions substituting RP2 with this twisted product. And it is still true that you generate non-orientable 3 manifolds.

Comment: @Paul, for surfaces that's an if and only if statement.  For 3-manifolds it's not an if and only if statement.  Taking connect-sum with a non-orientable manifold is non-orientable, but that's a trivial statement.

Comment: @RyanBudney I really don’t understand this discussion. Let the OP clarify what they want. You said (A) is false as is states and I say is (trivially) true.

Comment: @Paul thank you for discussion on my question. What I was hoping for in (A) was: every non orientable closed 3-manifold can be obtained as connected sum of closed orientable 3-manifold and $S^2\widetilde\times S^1$ (or any other basic non-orientable). According to Ryan Budney this is not true. My knowledge in area is too poor to add anything here.

Comment: @MarekMitros ok, then he is right and this is not true in dimension 3. I understood it in a different way: just if you can “produce” non orientable manifolds by taking connected sums with a non- orientable one. And this is true in every dimension

Comment: Still for me it is the question is there any relation between orientable and non-orientable ones. Connected sum with fixed non-orientable gives mapping in one direction. What could be the mapping in opposite direction ? Or what are the left-overs in non-orientable world (not obtained this way) ?

Answer (score 6):

For question D, I think the answer is negative. Consider the semidirect product $\Lambda=\mathbf{Z}^2\rtimes_A\mathbf{Z}$, with $A=\begin{pmatrix}25 & 7\\ 7 & 2\end{pmatrix}$. This is the $\pi_1$ of some SOL-type closed 3-manifold.

This matrix is not a square in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$, by a naive computation (use that the centralizer consists of symmetric matrices, and there exist no integers $a,b,c$ such that $(a^2+b^2,b^2+c^2)=(25,2)$). In addition one checks that every element of order 2 in the normalizer of $\langle A\rangle$ in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ is contained in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$. Therefore, any subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$ containing $\langle A\rangle$ as subgroup of index 2 is contained in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$. In addition, since the determinant of $A-I$ is $-25$, every subgroup of index $\le 5$ in $\Lambda$ contains $\mathbf{Z}^2$. Hence, if $\Gamma$ is a group containing $\Lambda$ as subgroup of index 2, then the intersection of subgroups of index $\le 4$ contains $\mathbf{Z}^2$, and taking the centralizer of its derived subgroup retrieves $\mathbf{Z}^2$, which is thus normal in the larger group $\Gamma$. The previous applies to the image of $\Gamma$ in $\Gamma/\mathbf{Z}^2$. So in case $\Gamma$ is torsion-free, the corresponding manifold is orientable.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain me last sentence of your answer ? How "torsion-free" lead to orientability ? My understanding is that loop changing orientation is infinite order in fundamental group of 3-manifold. Someone answered me on stack exchange, that there are no finite order elements in fundamental group of prime 3-manifold with infinte fundamental group.

Comment: This manifold is the mapping torus of some orientation-preserving self-diffeomorphism of the torus (given by the given matrix). So it's indeed orientable.